# encoding with php on win os file_exists does not work

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

Suddenly a file has arrived to our system with the following name:

```
20170925_ã‗├ó░°└═▒ñ░Ý_30├╩.mov
```

And the PHP function file_exists thinks the file is not present, I guess because the encoding used.
I am playing with PHP encoding functions to get the right encoding and be able to match the file, but I can't get it.
To solve accented string I did like that:

```
$filename = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $filename);
```

and it worked. But for those special characters I can't get the right way.

Anyone can help me?

EDIT: My script file is in UTF-8 and the PHP version we are using is PHP 7.0.9
A scandir returns this output:

```
 [2] => 20170925_ã=+ó¦°+-¦ñ¦Ý_30+-.mov
```

which it is not the filename characters. Seems like the extended ascii characters are not recognized by PHP¿?

Comment: Linux or Windows?

Comment: The host OS is windows (described in the title)

Comment: My bad, didnt watch out for that :) Are you using PHP5 or PHP7? Did you check that your script is indeed stored as UTF-8?

Comment: No problem at all ... I have edited the question with more details ... any idea?

Comment: `echo is_file("20170925_ã‗├ó░°└═▒ñ░Ý_30├╩.mov");` gives me `bool(true)`. Also, `var_dump(scandir("."))` gives me `string(53) "20170925_ã‗├ó░°└═▒ñ░Ý_30├╩.mov"`. Oddly enough on my server this does not work. Seems to be either a php setting or windows error, I will dig further into it

Comment: I still didn't get this characters to work with file_exists PHP function